# Como capturar la intensidad sonora de un tag <audio> o <video> en HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cómo se puede capturar la intensidad sonora, o algún tipo de información que pudiese facilitarme si un vídeo tiene sonido o no en un determinado momento.

El objetivo es tener en una aplicación web un tag de tipo `<video>` y poder marcar visualmente cuando está sonando o no.

Comment: algo como lo que hace chrome de señalarte qué pestañas están reproduciendo sonido?

Comment: bueno, algo tipo skype o hangout, imaginate una conferencia con varios elementos de video, y quiero saber cuales son los que están hablando en ese momento para marcarlo visualmente de alguna manera.

Comment: Es enrevesado, porque aunque el elemento de audio tenga volume = x, puede que no esté sonando ... quizá algo que analice la onda de sonido?

Comment: Si, algo así debería hacer. Quizás no es posible hacerlo desde JavaScript

Comment: Si, es la magia de la programacion, todo se puede xDD mira mi nueva respuesta a ver si te vale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) para lograr esto, necesitas hacer 4 cosas:

1. Crear un nodo analizador, que te permite tomar muestras del audio por pedazos y saber, por ejemplo, la intensidad de la señal en cada punto.
2. Crear un nodo procesador, que te permite procesar el audio a medida que se reproduce.
3. En el procesador, y utilizando el analizador, calcular el volumen de la señal para cada muestra que se procesa.
4. Conectar todo junto para: Visualizar la intensidad actual del audio y enviarlo también al speaker o output.

Ten en cuenta que son APIs bastante nuevas y aunque hay buen soporte es una opcion que te conviene usarla como Progressive Enhancement, osea que solo deberias incluirla en navegadores que lo soportan. Tambien es muy util en aplicaciones hechas con Electron o Apache Cordoba ya que se basan en Chromium y este soporta estas APIs muy bien.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que solo pude probar en Chrome 53. El audio no es el mejor pero es lo que encontre que permita cargar el audio desde aqui. El ejemplo tiene un overlay rojo que se pone mas intenso a medida que la potencia del audio sube.

El indicador del volumen promedio de cada muestra de audio es la variable `prom` 
la cual también uso para indicar la opacidad del `<div>`. Esto lo puedes usar, en base a un umbral. Por ejemplo, si es mayor a 10.0, activas el indicador de audio presente.

Esto es compatible con fuentes `getUserMedia` y `WebRTC` por lo que puedes utilizarlo sin problemas para indicar que el usuario esta hablando .

Salu2

```js
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');

// creamos un analyzer
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

// creamos un audio processor
var processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
// en el evento, verificamos si hay volumen o no 
processor.onaudioprocess = function(audio) {

  // tomar los datos del analyzer
  var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

  // calcular el volumen promedio
  var prom = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    prom += array[i];
  }

  prom = prom / array.length;

  // aqui ponemos la intensidad del volumen como opacidad del div
  overlay.style.opacity = prom/200;
  console.log(prom);

  // pasar los datos hacia el speaker
  var inputBuffer = audio.inputBuffer;
  var outputBuffer = audio.outputBuffer;

  for (var channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
    var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    var outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (var sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
      outputData[sample] = inputData[sample];
    }
  }
}

// conectar todo junto
var video = document.querySelector('audio');
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(processor);
processor.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<audio autoplay crossOrigin="anonymous" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://mdn.github.io/media-source-buffer/viper.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

NOTA: Este ejemplo es sensible al volumen del speaker, pero es una limitacion del ejemplo y con el objeto de simplificarlo y demostrar como funcionan estas APIs. Esto puede resolverse con facilidad utilizando un AudioSpliter y desviando la salida al analyzer sin necesidad de atacharse al volumen de salida.

Comment: Gracias por la solución, aunque todavía no he sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar en mi aplicación. En el ejemplo, el `src` del video lo cargas a traves de una URL. En mi caso, estoy utilizando WebRTC y haciendo un `attachMediaStream` por lo que el audio que recibo es en tiempo real. Esta solución me devuelve siempre el stream lleno de zeros. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola @oscarvady, puedes editar la pregunta y mostrar como estas conectando el contexto? quiza pueda ayudarte a resolverlo

Comment: He realizado lo mismo que has preparado en la solución. Crees que debería poder trocearlo igualmente aunque el stream de audio venga de un `attachMediaStream` de `WebRTC`?

Comment: Absolutamente, ambos son MediaStreamTrack.

Comment: @oscarvady https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination

Comment: eso es para crear un MediaStreamDestination, no? Yo recibo en el navegador un objeto de tipo `MediaStream`

Comment: Claro, eso seria para usarlo en la salida. Si lo quieres usar el MediaStream como entrada, es la funcion opuesta: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource

Comment: Gracias @rnd... en Firefox parece que tengo un problema... "El MediaStream pasado a createMediaElementSource tiene un recurso de origen cruzado, el nodo no mostrará nada."

Comment: @oscarvady es esta relacionado a CORS, el servidor que entrega el archivo de audio debe incluir las cabaceras Cors que autorizan al servidor origen de la pagina, es algo relacionado con HTTP no tiene nada que ver con el audio, sino con la seguridad del navegador. Si esta explicacion no te da la respuesta.. haz una nueva pregunta pues aqui no hay espacio para mucho mas XD Salu2

Comment: Mmmm vale @rnd, lo suponía. Aunque al ser un escenario WebRTC me imagino que el stream no lo está enviando el servidor... si no que se envían entre peers...